# Jhipster not loading font awesome icons

Tags: font-awesome, jhipster

I have font awesome installed in my jhipster project

When I import font awesome this way my icons dont appear-

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
```

But if I import font awesome this way they show up fine

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

I had a look through the font awesome troubleshooting guide but nothing stands out

Any help is much appreciated as I would like to host this file locally

Comment: first double check the path .. most probably its like path issue

Comment: path is 100% fine. it exists in that directory and no errors are being thrown in the chrome console.

Comment: then check about the font files attached in the CSS are in correct path of your local machine

Comment: they are yes, they are in the fonts directory on the same path as the css and the css files refer to ../fonts. I have not tampered with font awesome in anyway

Comment: it appears my font awesome installation got corrupt in some way. Deleting font awesome directory and re installing from bower has done the trick

Comment: The link above is incorrect, at least in the environment I tried it in. There isn't a hyphen in "font-awesome". The correct path:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css">

Comment: Thanks Rori - you had me double checking there but the path i had - with the hypen was correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is most likely caused by the minification so we have to use font-awesome.min.css and filter it out of the minification in the gulp "build" task.

But let's start from the very beginning.

1. Install font-awesome with bower saving it in the bower.json:

   ```
   bower install --save font-awesome
   ```
2. **DO NOT** add any "overrides" for the font-awesome into bower.json so that gulp-inject does not update content of the `<!-- bower:css -->` block in the index.html
3. Add the following code to the index.html:

   ```
   <!-- build:css content/css/font-awesome.css -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <!-- endbuild -->
   ```
4. Since font-awesome is a font we should include content of its "fonts" folder into the built results. We will just follow what was done for the "bootstrap" fonts and add the following code into the 'copy' task in the `gulpfile.js`:

   ```
   gulp.src(config.bower + 'font-awesome/fonts/*.*')
       .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
       .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'content/fonts/'))
       .pipe(rev())
       .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/fonts/'))
       .pipe(rev.manifest(config.revManifest, {
           base: config.dist,
           merge: true
       }))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/fonts/')),
   ```

   right before the line:

   ```
   gulp.src(config.app + 'content/**/*.{woff,woff2,svg,ttf,eot,otf}')
   ```
5. And last but not the least is to filter our minified CSS out of the CSS processing. All CSS files are being minified and concatenated in the `gulp/build.js`. First, we shall install [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter) package:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev gulp-filter
   ```

   Now we can include it into `gulp/build.js`:

   ```
   filter = require('gulp-filter')
   ```

   create custom filter:

   ```
   const faFilter = filter(['*','!font-awesome.css'], {restore: true});
   ```

   and, finally, use this custom filter wrapping existing cssTask():

   ```
   .pipe(faFilter)
   .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssTask()))
   .pipe(faFilter.restore)
   ```

Comment: This is an awesome comprehensive answer.  Worked exactly right and follows best practice.

Answer (score 6):

In *JHipster 5.0.1 with Angular* you should modify vendor.ts file.
For example if you want to add `faExpandArrowsAlt` Fontawesome icon, you should import it and then add it with `library.add(faExpandArrowsAlt);`

After changing the file run `yarn run webpack:build' tslint:disable`.

Comment: I was able to use the `src/main/webapp/app/config/icon-loader.ts` file to get the same effect in *JHipster v5.1 with React*.

Answer (score 1):

In *JHipster V5.1 with React*, to add the `faUsers` icon, I just edited `src/main/webapp/app/config/icon-loader.ts` and I was just able to use that icon within a `<FontAwesomeIcon icon="users" />`.

Comment: how can we use it in jhipster  angular project?

Answer (score 0):

it appears my font awesome installation got corrupt in some way. Deleting font awesome directory and re installing from bower has done the trick

Answer (score 0):

That's because cssnano made some mistakes with font-awesome.css, and no with .min file.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a 'fonts' folder in your contents directory and add your font files there, Jhipster will load all those files via gulp